# phpunit - How to test property as object

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have two classes.

```
class Posts {

  public function retrieve(): array {
   // Do something
  }

}
```

And

```
class PostsGateway {

 public $entity;

 function __construct() {
  $this->entity = new Posts();
 }

 public function retrieve(): array {
  return $this->entity->retrieve();
 }

}
```

I want to test the behaviour of PostsGateway class' `retrieve` method. 
`entity` property is an object, so I am assigning this property an another mock which is for `Posts` class.

I am setting expectation on `Posts` mock which I have assigned to `entity` property in `PostsGateway` mock.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PostsGatewayTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * Test `retrieve` behavior.
     */
    public function testRetrieve() {
        $postsMock                = $this->createMock( Posts::class );
        $postsGatewayMock         = $this->createMock( PostsGateway::class );
        $postsGatewayMock->entity = $postsMock;

        $postsGatewayMock->entity->expects( $this->once() )->method( 'retrieve' );

        $data = $postsGatewayMock->retrieve();
    }

}
```

When I am running the test it is failing with following error.

```
PostsGatewayTest::testRetrieve

Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'retrieve' when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well mocking a class it's not enough, you need to bind the mocked class to the real class so PostsGateway could understand about it. In this case, you can use constructor injection to pass the mocked class.

```
$mockPosts = $this->createMock(Posts::class);
$mockPosts->expects($this->once())->method('retrieve')->withAnyParameters();

$postsGateway = new PostsGateway($mockPosts);
$postsGateway->retrieve();
```

And the PostsGateway class should change to

```
class PostsGateway {

    public $entity;

    function __construct($posts) {
        $this->entity = $posts;
    }

    public function retrieve(): array {
        return $this->entity->retrieve();
    }

}
```